# What is property and invoked method with body in braces (in Swift)

Tags: ios, swift

How it's called and where to find information in Swift what is when for reading property or invoked method it used body in brace. 
Example:

Property:

```
mySerialQueue.sync { task("New Task") }

SomeObj someObj = obj {
    name = "some name"
}
```

Method:

```
workItem.notify(queue: DispatchQueue.main) {
    if let imageData = data {
        eiffelImage.image = UIImage(data: imageData)
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you looking for the word "closure" (in Objective-C, it's "Block")

Comment: [Swift Language Guide: Closures](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Closures.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH11-ID94)

Comment: Hmm, may be!) Thanks, guys!

Comment: In particular, those are "trailing closures". But really, read the language guide.

Answer (score 0):

From [“Trailing Closures” in *The Swift Programming Language*](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Closures.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH11-ID102):

> If you need to pass a closure expression to a function as the function’s final argument and the closure expression is long, it can be useful to write it as a *trailing closure* instead. A trailing closure is written after the function call’s parentheses, even though it is still an argument to the function. When you use the trailing closure syntax, you don’t write the argument label for the closure as part of the function call.
>
> […]
>
> If a closure expression is provided as the function or method’s only argument and you provide that expression as a trailing closure, you do not need to write a pair of parentheses `()` after the function or method’s name when you call the function: